# How to add conditional branch instruction without else option?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, instructions

I am trying get my IR to look like below. Is it possible to achieve this in LLVM?

```
entry:
 %2 = call i32 @func()
 %3 = icmp ne i32 %2, 0, !dbg
  br i1 %3, label %if.then.block

  call void @abc()
  ret void

if.then.block:
  ; Insert instructions for the "if.then.block"
  ; ...

  ret void
```

I tried an approach which gave my branch instruction with a else block for false case. I am not looking for that.

Comment: Is that not already valid LLVM-IR?  If so, you have IR that looks like that.  Did you want some other tool to **generate** IR like that from something else you haven't shown or mentioned?  e.g. clang to generate that LLVM-IR from C?  Or some LLVM optimization pass to turn different IR into this?  Not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @PeterCordes No, it's not valid LLVM IR. You can't have a conditional branch with only one target and you can't have multiple terminators (or any other instructions following a terminator) in the same block.

Comment: But you do have an else path with something to do on that path.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

The whole point of a basic block is that there's no (local) control flow inside of it. You can jump to the beginning of a block and you can jump out of it at the very end through the single terminator instruction. Between that it's just a linear sequence of instructions.

So not only can't you have a conditional branch with only one target, you also can't further instructions in the same block following the branch. The branch terminates the block.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem when creating my compiler. You can check if there's an else block available in your parse tree. If it's not, then you still emit the else branch but leave it empty and just terminate it with a branch to a merging block. Here's an example:

```
...
  br i1 %15, label %then, label %else

then:                                             ; preds = %entry
  ret i32 55

else:                                             ; preds = %entry
  br label %merge ; no else block in original source code, so we just jump into merge block

merge:                                            ; preds = %else
  %16 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 44, ptr %16, align 4
  ret i32 2
```